# A ring is commutative if the solution of $ab=ca$ is always unique

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> **Gallian 12.8:** Show that a ring is commutative if $ab=ca \implies b=c$ when $a\neq 0$.

It's an odd statement. I tried to approach the problem by proving it directly or by contradiction, but I honestly got nowhere. Looking forward to some hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x,y\in R$, $x\neq 0$. We want to show $xy=yx$. Set $a=x$, $b=yx$, $c=xy$. Then $ab=xyx=ca$ so $b=c$ so $xy=yx$.

For $x=0$ we clearly also have $xy=yx$ for all $y$.

Comment: Good solution, but the OP asked for a hint and not the answer

Comment: Yes I know. I was unable to find a good way to write a hint, and "try $a=x$, $b=yx$, $c=xy$" is so close to the complete solution that I rather posted that.

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking of something like "plug in some value for $b$ and $c$ so that the statment that $b = c$ is the statment that $x$ and $y$ commute," but I am not sure if that would have been too vague.

Comment: It's cool, I'll use this idea in the next exercises. I looked at the first line then completed the proof.